# Why does the Arduino Due have a native and USB programming port?

Tags: arduino-due

According to the schematics, the Arduino Due has two USB inputs:

1. Native
2. Programming

Why is this? And when would I use the different ports?

Comment: Is there a mapping of the native port to serial pins? The programming port maps to 0 and 1 correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either port can be used for programming, but the native USB port lets you do other things:

> It also enables the Due to emulate a USB mouse or keyboard to an attached computer. To
>   use these features, see the [Mouse and Keyboard library reference pages](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard).
>
> The Native USB port can also act as a USB host for connected
>   peripherals such as mice, keyboards, and smartphones. To use these
>   features, see the [USBHost reference pages](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost). <sub>http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue</sub>

So you can use the Due to interface with USB devices or connect it to your computer and have it act like a USB device.

Comment: So, it would be possible to attach a mouse to USB native, and detect and Register mouse movements in the host laptop via the other USB input?

Comment: I think only the native one can do both of those things. The other one is for programming only.